# ArcGIS - run a tool thousands of times

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, image-analyst

I want to sample a labelled satellite image with random points and create a confusion matrix to compare the accuracy of land classes. I wish to repeat this thousands of times to see how the accuracy of the confusion matrix changes.

I have the Python code for generating random sample points, updating the sample points and creating a confusion matrix. Each time I run it, it will over-write the previous outputs. How can I export this as a CSV?

I want the code:

1. It runs 1,000 times,
2. It creates a CSV file that saves the confusion matrix output tool each time before being over-written

The below code runs 1,000 times and creates 1,000 confusion matrix files. Instead of storing the matrixes as 1000 JSON tables, I want it to export the 1000 confusion matrixes as CSV files.

```py
import arcpy from arcpy.sa import * 
from arcpy import env #this allows you to overwrite inputs... 
env.overwriteOutput = True

for i in range(1000):
    # Create random sample points with ground truth values    
    arcpy.ia.CreateAccuracyAssessmentPoints(r"ground_truth_raster", r"sample_points", "GROUND_TRUTH", 500, "EQUALIZED_STRATIFIED_RANDOM", None) 

    # Update sample points with classified raster values     
    arcpy.ia.UpdateAccuracyAssessmentPoints(r"classified_raster", "sample_points", r"sample_points_updated", "CLASSIFIED", None, None)

    # Create confusion matrix     
    arcpy.ia.ComputeConfusionMatrix("sample_points_updated", r"confusionmatrix"+str(i))
```

Comment: So at this point you're asking how to convert one JSON to one CSV, but put it inside the loop, with a unique name?  According to the documentation, it seems that you could output different dBase files, just by adding a `.dbf` suffix to the output table  name.  Not sure where the JSON is being generated, though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
    arcpy.conversion.TableToTable(r"confusionmatrix"+str(i), r"path_of_folder_to_save_to", r"confusionmatrix"+str(i)+".csv")
```

This will convert a table to a CSV, according to the documentation at:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm

NB:  I'm not sure what you mean about JSON, in this context.